$\sigma$ algebra is $\mu$-trivial iff all measurable functions are a.s. constant.
We call a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on $X$ $\mu$-trivial iff $\mu(\Sigma)=\{0,1\}$.
I am supposed to show that this is equivalent to all measurable functions $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ being a.e. constant.
I think I was able to show this by considering: $\{A \in \Sigma \ | \ \mu(A)=1\}$ and using Zorn’s lemma to show that this has a minimal element $M$ under the inclusion. Now if $|f(M)| \geq 2$ we would need to have measurable sets $U,V \subseteq M$ and if both of them had measure $0$, or one of them had measure $1$, that would be a contradiction to the minimality of $M$ and thus $|f(M)| \geq 2$ iff there is a set with measure strictly between $0$ and $1$. This shows the claim.
But I’m sceptical, does one really need to invoke the axiom of choice to show the claim?

Hint: Let $c=\inf {a: \mu (f^{-1}([a,\infty)))=1}$  and show that $f=c$ a.s.

Suppose that $\mu(\Sigma)=\{0,1\}$ and let $f$ be measurable. We may assume without loss of generality that $f$ maps into an interval $[a,b]$, for we might replace it by composition with a bijection, say $\arctan\circ f$. Write $I_{0,1}=[a,b]$ and consider dyadic partitions
$$
[a,b]=\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^n}I_{n,j}.
$$
Then, for each $n$, the $2^n$ disjoint sets $X_{n,j}=f^{-1}(I_{n,j})$, $j=1,\ldots,2^n$, form a partition of $X$. Since $1=\mu(X)=\sum_j\mu(X_{n,j})$, for each $n$  there exists a single $j_n$ with $\mu(X_{n,j_n})=1$. Then $f=f\,1_{X_{n,j }}$ a.e. Necessarily (by looking at their measures) we have $X_{n+1,j_{n+1}}\subset X_{n,j}$ for all $n$. Let $X_0=\bigcap_nX_{n,j_n}$; by continuity of the measure, $\mu(X_0)=1$. We also have $I_{n+1,j+1}\subset I_{n,j}$ for all $n$. Then $\bigcap_nI_{n,j_n}=\{s\}$ for some $s\in [a,b]$. We have
$$
\mu(f^{-1}(\{s\})=\mu\bigg(f^{-1}\bigg(\bigcap_nI_{n,j_n}\bigg)\bigg)
=\mu\bigg(\bigcap_nf^{-1}(I_{n,j_n})\bigg)=\mu(X_0)=1.
$$
Thus $f=s$ a.e.
Conversely, if $\alpha,\beta\in \mu(\Sigma)$ and $0<\alpha<\beta$, there exist $A,B \in \Sigma$ with $\mu(A)=\alpha$ and $\mu(B)=\beta$. If $\mu(A\cap B )>0$, since   $$\mu(A\cap B)\leq\mu(A)<\mu(B),$$ we have $\gamma=\mu(B\setminus A\cap B)>0$. Then the two sets $A\cap B,B\setminus A\cap B\in \Sigma$ are disjoint and with positive measure. So $f=1_{A\cap B}+5\,(1_{B\setminus A\cap B})$ is a measurable function that is not constant a.e.
And when $\mu(A\cap B)=0$, the sets $C=A\setminus A\cap B $ and $D=B\setminus A\cap B $ are disjoint with $\mu(C)=\alpha$ and $\mu(D)=\beta$. So we can construct $f=1_C+5\,(1_D)$.

As a comment, I don't think you can use Zorn as you did. Zorn's Lemma implies arbitrary unions/intersections and these don't belong with $\sigma$-algebras. Consider  $\Sigma\subset \mathcal P (\mathbb R)$ of those sets which are either countable or co-countable, and $\mu$ is $1$ on the uncountable sets and $0$ on the countable ones. Then there's no minimal set of measure $1$, as you can always remove a point.

Hello @MartinArgerami, in the second part: how can we conclude that $A\cap B$ has positive measure? Could one use $A$ instead of $A\cap B$ in $f$?

@Snoop: good catch. I have addressed that now.

Thanks for your answer! How do you know $A,B$ have non-zero measure (consider f.e. $f(x)=x$ and the Lebesgue measure). Also, I can use Zorn because I need to show every totally ordered set has a lower bound, and totally ordered sets are countable (just order them and „count along the order“)

Ok sorry the latter argument obviously doesn’t work.

That $f$ does not satisfy "Suppose that $f$ is measurable and it takes two distinct values $a, b$ on non-null sets".

Yeah but $f$ only needs to be non constant a.s.

Indeed. I changed the argument. Please see the edit.
